# Why am I getting 404 errors on my Mean production app?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku

I'm trying to publish a node.js server on Heroku that serves an angular app on all requests (minus /api endpoint). The angular app works perfectly fine when I run the node.js server on my local machine + running ng build --watch on the angular app. The issue I'm facing is I'm getting 404 errors on the angular routes when I push the server to Heroku.

This is the error I'm getting in Heroku logs: 2021-03-28T20:38:50.700486+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/dist/client/index.html'

After looking into it more, I found that the dist file that is built on "npm run build" isn't deploying to heroku. Posting my package.json file below.

Here is my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path')
const api = require('./routes/api');

const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/api', api)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'client/dist/client'));
app.get('**', function(req,res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'client/dist/client/index.html'));

});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    console.log((path.join( __dirname  + '/client/dist/client/index.html')))
  })
```

Package.Json:

```
{
  "name": "spotify-playlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: seems pretty clear: `client/dist/client/index.html` doesn't exist in the file system (e.g. on your disk). So make sure you're pointing to the correct dir/files.

Comment: It seems to be working fine when I run "node index.js" on my local machine. Seems like the file exists too.

Comment: Cool, but you weren't asking about your local setup, you were asking about Heroku, so: fire up a heroku console for your app  either online or CLI) and find out what _it_ has as filesystem?

Comment: Sorry i'm a bit inexperienced in this. What am I looking for exactly on Heroku?

Comment: go to your app, then in the upper right there's the "more..." menu, click it, and pick the console option, then tell it to run `bash`. That'll get your a bash session that you can use to `ls` and `cd` your way around the file system, to see if the files/dirs that should exist, exist. Also, remember to check whether you've made sure that Heroku actually builds your `dist` code/files/etc instead of merely running `npm start`.

Comment: Looks like I cant cd into the "dist" file on heroku. Could it be the ng build isn't building the file structure the way I want it to?

Comment: What do you mean you can't cd into it? Either it exists (e.g. it shows up on an `ls`) and you cd into it just fine, or it doesn't exist (And then it's not "I can't cd into it", it's "it doesn't exist" =)

Comment: It doesn't exist. Sorry learning as I go along here! I ran "ls" in the client folder and nothing came up

Comment: So what builds that dir? Because this is not your server app going wrong: it's your deploy script not running your build, so what are you telling Heroku to run?

Comment: I'm running npm run build prior to deployment

Comment: no, don't tell me, _tell everyone_: update your post with the details that are clearly important here =) make sure to say what your heroku deploy script looks like, and show that `npm build` _actually_ builds those dirs (protip: delete you dist dir locally, then run the same commands you're telling heroku to run: do things still work? Because in this case, I'm pretty sure they won't and you're missing a step in your heroku script)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Your package.json doesn't have anything in it that builds a dist dir? So you're going to have to probably explain why you're using that dir, and explain what is supposed to build it.

Comment: Solved: I was working within the incorrect package.json file. I had two package.json files. 1) from inside the angular app and 2) from creating the node server. To fix the issue, I deleted the package.json originally built for the node server and put all my scripts into the package.json file within my angular app. I then moved my angular file out of a folder called "client" into the root folder alongside my index.js file. Ran perfectly fine after that.

Comment: Nice. In that case you'll want to either delete the question, or write an answer to your question if you think your question is general enough that future visitors will benefit from finding it.

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I deployed my MEAN application on Heroku so I will share my configuration with you.

In **angular.json** find **"outputPath"** and set it to the public/static folder of the server in your case. In mine it is `"outputPath": "./server/static"`

In the server code be sure to set the folder in which the Angular app will be built as **static**. In my case I have the following:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__basedir, 'static')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
            res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__basedir, '/static', 'index.html'))
        });
```

In package.json you need the following two scripts:

```
"start": "node server/index.js" // This should point to your index.js file, whereever it is
"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod" // This one builds the angular app before your index.js serves it
```

P.S. Ignore the **server folder** in my case **index.js** is located inside a server folder as well as the **static** folder